# How to process the text received for OCR engine

Tags: image-processing, ocr, text-processing, text-extraction

I am using OCR to extract text from images. Although I am getting almost 90% accuracy in this process the big problem remains that the output is in form of a large chuck of text that includes lot of noise.

```
{"text_block":[{"text":"--'mw.lu\"....-\nmd(path&8act)\naarogyampathologylaborator\nconsultingpatholog\n'mnnnmnm\n00005'1si\npatient'sname:kantibhaipatelage/sex:71years/maie\nref.by:dr.ketanshuklams.mch.reg.date:27106120151914\nlab.ref.no.:ary-881515reportingdate.27106/20152023\nhemogramreport\ntestresult5referenceinterval\nhemoglobin:7.0gldl.[m:a1418.f:12'16gldl]\ntotalrbccpunt:2.71..milllcmm*..wi;425.6'gl':3.6-5.0mill/cmm]\n(.xl.e.''\n3totalwbccount:34,890'icmm;[4.000-10,000/cmm]\ndifferentialwbccount:\npolymorphs:88\nlymphocytes:09\n,eosin0phils:01\nmonocytes:02\nbasophils.:00\nbandcells'\nsmearstudy:-\nrbc\n%[50-70%)\n%[2030%1\n%[14%1\n%[26%]\n%[0-1%1\n%\nparasites\"malarialparasitesarenotseen.\n'rbcsarehypochromic&showsanisopoikiloc\nmyeloblast:.'%\npromyelo:,%':'\nmyelocyte:,\"lo\nmetamyelo:'%\nblastcells:':%\nnormoblasts:'%;'\nytesis.\nplatelets\"plateletsareadequateinnumber.'\nwbc'thrispolymorphnuclaerleucocytosiswith\"\n3other''*fewnormoblastsareseen.''\nerythfdcytesedimentationrate[modifiedwestergren]:\n-afterl1hour]mm[m:1-7mm,f:312mm]\n'after2hours.:mm(m:715mm.f:10-18mm]\nbleedingtime:muinsec,[upto5minutesj\nclottingtime:minsec-[upto9minutes],.\np.cv.-:25.2%[m:42-52f:36-48%]i\nm.cv..:93.0i\"femtolitre[82-98femtolitre]\nm.ch.:25.8pgfcell[2634pgiceli]\nm.ch.c.:278'.'gldl..[32-37g],v\nr.d.w.:.24.0%''[11-16>%]j\ntotalplateletcount:252300'''lac'lcm'm'--\"l['1'.'54.5lac/cmm]\nabsoluteeosinophilcount:icmm[404ooicmm1\ncomments:hypochromic&normocytic'anemia.\n(doneonxs-800i,sysmex)\nfirstfloor,shohamcomplex.nr.man!\nphone:26463535.30930122'\n,.hi'\nehabhubuilding,navrangsuxroads,am\ntlme:800am\n'.$\"1.\n\"u'u'\n.:m..-.--.--","left":8,"top":0,"width":888,"height":1396}]}
```

My question is that how can I process this text to extract specific information out of it? `Eg. A pointer to "Haemoglobin"`  I am not aware of the noise removal and feature extraction steps to be followed after this. You may also notice that there are few spelling mistakes that also needs to be accounted.

Any idea on how to proceed with this problem including references to research papers or libraries would be really helpful.

Comment: How do you plan to tell noise from data? Especially since your sample has "hemoglobin", not "haemoglobin"? While it'd be easy to scan for "ha?emoglobin via a regex, what if that anchor gets mangled beyond what a simple regex/wildcard can account for?  And if the main text is mangled, how will you be able to trust the `7.0gldl`?

Comment: I came here looking for the same answer. Someone from research background might have an answer to this.

Comment: That gets into "way too broad". You can't expect to get an entire research field stuck into a "simple" answer here.

Comment: I understand your point but I find it almost impossible to break the question into smaller addressable form. Do you have any suggestions?